# EF Core: How to reuse same expression in different query contexts

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entity types:

```
public partial class StudentEntity
{
   public int Age { get; set; }
   
   public int GroupId { get; set; }
}

public partial class GroupEntity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public virtual Collection<StudentEntity> Students { get; set; }
}
```

and I have an expression which I want to reuse:

```
Expression<Func<StudentEntity, bool>> isAdult = student => student.Age > 21;
```

There are two scenarios where I need to use the above expression:

when querying all adult students

```
IEnumerable<StudentEntity> students = context.Students
                                             .Where(isAdult)
                                             .ToList();
```

and when querying all groups with at least one adult

```
IEnumerable<GroupEntity> groups = context.Groups
                                         .Where(g => g.Students
                                                      .Where(isAdult)
                                                      .Any())
                                         .ToList();
```

The problem is that in the second scenario the `Where` clause is applied on `Collection` and it requires a `Func<StudentEntity, bool>` and not an `Expression<Func<StudentEntity, bool>>`.

Passing `isAdult.Compile()` to the `Where` method leads to a successful compilation but later to an unhandled exception at runtime due to the inability of the framework to translate the compiled into a method expression.

Is there a way to reuse the existing expression in the different querying contexts having the mentioned above entity structure/hierarchy?

Comment: Maybe `g => g.Students.AsQueryable().Any(isAdult)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

I just tested something similar with Entity Framework Core 5 running in LINQPad, and it looks like Jonathan Barclay's suggestion to call `.AsQueryable()` should work.

```
IEnumerable<GroupEntity> groups = context.Groups
                                         .Where(g => g.Students
                                                      .AsQueryable()
                                                      .Where(isAdult)
                                                      .Any())
                                         .ToList();
```

### Original Answer

This is a [good use case](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#plugging-expressions-into-entitysets--entitycollections-the-problem) for [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), which would allow you to do this:

```
IEnumerable<GroupEntity> groups = context.Groups.AsExpandable()
                                         .Where(g => g.Students
                                                      .Where(isAdult.Compile())
                                                      .Any())
                                         .ToList();
```

Comment: I have no experience with LINQKit, but doesn't this mean EF needs to load ALL Students into memory because the `isAdult` criteria is never turned into SQL? Not that this is different from OPs example.

Comment: @Xerillio: No, the `AsExpandable()` extension wraps the query in a special evaluator that will remove the call to `.Compile()` and replace it with a copy of the `isAdult` expression, so it'll work just like you'd hope it would. See the link I posted for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that without special expression preprocessing. This can be done by LINQKit library:

```cs
var groups = context.Groups
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(g => g.Students
                .Where(e => isAdult.Invoke(e))
                .Any()
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Could you please explain why does @Johnathan Barclay comment to convert to `IQueryable` using the `.AsQueryable` method wont work?

Comment: It's because your `Where` inside Lambda. And compile will create non translatable expression anyway.

Comment: Actually `AsQueryable` trick works in this particular scenario. It doesn't in some other scenarios, for instance projecting from reference navigation property (hence `AsQueryable` cannot be used). This is more generic approach, although it's not the only 3rd party extension for the task in question.

Comment: @IvanStoev Could you please give an example or explain what do you mean by projecting from reference navigation property? 
Do you mean something like this: `context.GroupLeaders.Where(gl => gl.Group.Students.AsQueryable().Where(isAdult).Any()).ToList()`, where Group is a reference navigation property of the Group Leader Entity?

Comment: Projecting (projection) term maps to LINQ `Select`. As I said, it's a different case. Yours is filtering (`Where`) predicate lambda injection.